# Compare & sort an array of objects against another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I currently have an array of objects as shown below:

```
$aa = new StdClass;
$aa->name = 'aa';
$aa->index = 30;
$bb = new StdClass;
$bb->name = 'bb';
$bb->index = 30;
$cc = new StdClass;
$cc->name = 'cc';
$cc->index = 10;
$dd = new StdClass;
$dd->name = 'dd';
$dd->index = 20;
$ee = new StdClass;
$ee->name = 'ee';
$ee->index = 10;
```

I have placed my objects into an array for sorting:

```
$arr = [$aa, $bb, $cc, $dd];
```

I also have an additional array which I would like to be used for sorting the objects in order at the index e.g. `$aa->index`:

```
$map = [30, 20, 10, 10, 30];
```

An expected result would be:

```
[$aa, $dd, $cc, $ee, $bb]
```

The other of `$aa` and `$bb` is undefined, they must simply not repeat and all indices must be assigned somewhere.

What would be the best way to arrange `$arr` in order set by `$map` **WITHOUT** the use of a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: How do you decide whether the first index - `30` - refers to the object `$aa` or `$bb`?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil randomly, I suppose

Comment: Given your example - is `[$aa, $dd, $cc, $cc, $aa]` a correct output?

Comment: No, should be [$aa, $dd, $cc, $ee, $bb] or somehow like that. No repeats

Comment: `$map` is always the same `[30, 20, 10, 10, 30]`? If not, How this order is defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476 → *Sorting into a manual, static order*

Comment: This is not a duplicate, using array_search in this case won't work because the reference $order (or $map in this case) has duplicated values, all objects from original array with the same index property will be sorted one next to the other regardless the position in $order or $map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure if I understood the question right, but here's an attempt at your problem:

```
$aa = new stdClass;
$aa->name = 'aa';
$aa->index = 30;
$bb = new stdClass;
$bb->name = 'bb';
$bb->index = 30;
$cc = new stdClass;
$cc->name = 'cc';
$cc->index = 10;
$dd = new stdClass;
$dd->name = 'dd';
$dd->index = 20;
$ee = new stdClass;
$ee->name = 'ee';
$ee->index = 10;


$arr = [$aa, $bb, $dd, $cc,  $ee];
$map = [30, 30 , 10,  20];

function sort_ish($arr, $map)
{
    $return = [];

    while($element = array_shift($map))
    {
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
        {
            if($element == $value->index)
            {
                $return[] = $value;
                unset($arr[$key]);
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

print_r(sort_ish($arr, $map));
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
(
    [name] => aa
[index] => 30
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
(
    [name] => bb
[index] => 30
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
(
    [name] => cc
[index] => 10
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
(
    [name] => dd
[index] => 20
        )

)
```

---

Really, I had to use a foreach.

On a different note, I had a lot of fun with this question, even if I didn't get it right. Thanks OP.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by technically not calling a `foreach()` loop, but I am looping using a recursive function. All you need to do do is pass the object array (`$arr`) as the first param and your array map (`$mapArr`) as your second to the function **`mrSorty()`**. `mrSorty()` will then take it from here passing your object array through magical functions such as `array_search()` and `ksort()`.

```
$arr = [$aa, $bb, $cc, $dd, $ee];
$mapArr = [30, 20, 10, 10, 30];

function mrSorty($arr, $mapArr, $objCount=0) {

    static $newArr; 

      if ((count($mapArr)) > 0 && $objCount < ($objCount+count($mapArr)) ) {

            $obj = $arr[$objCount];
            $key = array_search($obj->index, $mapArr);
            $newArr[$key] = $obj;
            unset($mapArr[$key]);
            mrSorty($arr, $mapArr, ++$objCount);
      } 

      ksort($newArr); //Sort the Array by Key
      return $newArr; 
}



$arrayReturn = mrSorty($arr, $mapArr); //Array of Objects & Array Map

var_dump($arrayReturn);
```

**Output**

```
array(5) {
[0] => object(stdClass) #1 (2) { ["name"]= > string(2)"aa" ["index"] => int(30)}
[1] => object(stdClass) #4 (2) { ["name"]= > string(2) "dd" ["index"] => int(20)}
[2] => object(stdClass) #3 (2) { ["name"]= > string(2) "cc" ["index"] => int(10)}
[3] => object(stdClass) #5 (2) { ["name"]= > string(2) "ee" ["index"] => int(10)}
[4] => object(stdClass) #2 (2) { ["name"]= > string(2)"bb" ["index"] => int(30)}
}
```

Edit:

*On a serious note, if you need to me elaborate then let me know.*